# How do you access SimpleXML nodes in a namespace environment?

Tags: php, xml, dom, soap, simplexml

How do you access PHP SimpleXML nodes in a namespace environment?

I want to pragmatically add `<param>value</param>` under `<request>`. Not just edit it in a string.

```
$xml = \SimpleXMLElement(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . PHP_EOL
  . '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' . PHP_EOL
  . '  <soap:Body>' . PHP_EOL
  . '    <Function xmlns="https://webservices.sveaekonomi.se/webpay">' . PHP_EOL
  . '      <request />' . PHP_EOL
  . '    </Function>' . PHP_EOL
  . '  </soap:Body>' . PHP_EOL
  . '</soap:Envelope>'
);
```

I have attempted the following:

```
#1
$xml->Envelope->Body->Function->request->addChild('param', 'value');

#2
$xml->children('https://webservices.sveaekonomi.se/webpay')->request->addChild('param', 'value');

#3
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('swp', 'https://webservices.sveaekonomi.se/webpay');
$xml->xpath('/swp:request')->addChild('param', 'value');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made a few common mistakes here, so I'll go through each in turn.

Let's start with the beginning of your first attempt:

```
$xml->Envelope->Body->...
```

SimpleXML doesn't have a separate object for the document, only the root element - in this case, `Envelope`. So you don't need to say `->Envelope`, you're already there. Without namespaces being involved, you would write:

```
$xml->Body->...
```

However, the object *doesn't* automatically "select" the namespace of that element, so you have to either immediately call `->children()`, or pass the namespace you want to pre-select into the constructor:

```
$xml->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->...
// Or
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString, 0, false, 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xml->Body->...
```

With that in mind, we get to:

```
$xml->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->Function->...
```

This fails because `Function` isn't in the same namespace as `Body`. The way I like to think of it is that [the `->children()` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) is a "switch namespace" method, so we switch to the right namespace and carry on:

```
$xml->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body
    ->children('https://webservices.sveaekonomi.se/webpay')->Function->request
    ->addChild('param', 'value');
```

This will work!

---

Your second attempt makes a different mistake:

```
$xml->children('https://webservices.sveaekonomi.se/webpay')->request->...
```

The "children" method doesn't let you jump deep into the document - as its name suggests, it gives you the *direct children* of an element, not the grand-children, great grand-children, and so on. The `$xml` variable points to the "Envelope" node, and that doesn't have a child called "request".

There isn't a built-in method for "any descendant of", except by using XPath...

---

Although seemingly completely different, your third attempt actually fails for the same reason:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('swp', 'https://webservices.sveaekonomi.se/webpay');
$xml->xpath('/swp:request')->...
```

The `/` operator in XPath similarly means "children of"; there *is* an operator for "any descendant of", which is `//`, so you would have got *nearly* the right result with this:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('swp', 'https://webservices.sveaekonomi.se/webpay');
$xml->xpath('//swp:request')->...
```

That will fail for a slightly more subtle reason: [the `xpath()` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) of SimpleXML always returns an *array*, not an object, so you have to ask for the first element (`[0]`) of that array.

So the working XPath code is this:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('swp', 'https://webservices.sveaekonomi.se/webpay');
$xml->xpath('//swp:request')[0]->addChild('param', 'value');
```

Comment: Wow that answer surely deserves a lot of appreciation! Thanks you so much! Upvoting and marking as the accepted answer to the question! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dealing with xml one way to approach it is to use xpath and `local-name()`:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    <soap:Body> 
      <Function xmlns="https://webservices.sveaekonomi.se/webpay"> 
        <request/>
      </Function> 
    </soap:Body> 
  </soap:Envelope>
';
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$destination = ($doc->xpath('//*[local-name()="request"]'));
$destination[0]->addChild('param', 'value');
echo $doc->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    <soap:Body> 
      <Function xmlns="https://webservices.sveaekonomi.se/webpay"> 
        <request><param>value</param></request>
      </Function> 
    </soap:Body> 
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Interesting, I learned something new here :)